# How to Manage ScrollView(Up And Down) According Keyboard was Show And Hide in Screen Using NSNotificationCenter in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

Consider I have one screen, and in this screen I have 10 textfields, now my issue is when keyboard is open then keyboard is up on my 3 textfield. so how can i manage this using UIScrollView and NSNotification Center?

Comment: You can use this swift code into Objective C. Just need to write this code once and use anywhere. Write this method in your BaseViewController or MasterViewController that if you created. Please see :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41519044/uiscrollview-stops-scrolling-on-keyboard-dismiss/41519289?noredirect=1#comment70252225_41519289

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I have One Code For this, I am Sure its Definitely Work For you.

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
   CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]   CGRectValue].size;
   UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
   MyScrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
   MyScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
 }

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
   UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
   MyScrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
   MyScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

Comment: where i need add to addobserver method?

Comment: You need to add this addObserver Method in ViewDidLoad Or Any Other Method Of ViewController Life Cycle as rer your Requirement.  method works is notify to NSNotificationCenter for, Keyboard Show And Hide,

Answer (score 0):

You can create a category of UIView to make it has capability to Observe the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` Notification

like below

```
@implementation UIView (PFInputViewControl)

-(void)setupKeyboardShow:(void(^)(NSNotification *notifacation))showblock hide:(void (^)(NSNotification *notifacation))hideblock {
      NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
      NSOperationQueue *mainQuene = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
      [notificationCenter addObserverForName:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil queue:mainQuene usingBlock:showblock];

      [notificationCenter addObserverForName:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil queue:mainQuene usingBlock:hideblock];

     //Setting tap hid gesture when the keyboard is showed and remove the tap gesture when it disappear
     [self setupForDismissKeyboard];
}

-(void)setupForDismissKeyboard{
     NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
     UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapHidAction)];

     __weak typeof(self)weakSelf = self;
     NSOperationQueue *mainQuene = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
     [notificationCenter addObserverForName:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil queue:mainQuene usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) {
         [weakSelf addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
     }];

     [notificationCenter addObserverForName:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil queue:mainQuene usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) {
         [weakSelf removeGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
     }];
 }

@end
```

And in your usage ,you just need to import the category file,and then setup the code

```
    [self.view setupKeyboardShow:^(NSNotification *notification) {

         //========== do your action when keyboard is show ==========
         //....
         //
         //such as
         NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];
         //get the size of key board
         CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
         //make transform when key board show
         self.view.y = - kbSize.height;

     } hide:^(NSNotification *notification) {
         //.... key board hid action
         self.view.y = 0;
         //....
     }];


     //setup keyboard dismiss when touch the screen out side the keyboard
     [self.view setupForDismissKeyboard];
```